# How do I prevent redirections when using URLSession?

Tags: swift

I am trying to prevent redirections (ie server responding with 302 and Swift following to said url, ultimately returning that page's content) when using URLSession in Swift.
This question has been asked many times on this site, but none of the answers work, at least not anymore.

Here is the full code I'm using (the delegate part lifted straight from here, but not the only format I've tried) and that supposedly prevents redirections but does not actually work :

```
class MySession: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
     // Handles redirection
     func URLSession(session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: (URLRequest?) -> Void) {
        // Stops the redirection, and returns (internally) the response body.
        print("PASSING") // Never fires
        completionHandler(nil)
     }
}

class MappingHandler: NSObject {
    // --------
    // A bunch of other code
    // --------

    // Makes the request while preventing the automated redirection TODO DOES NOT WORK
    func makeRequest(urlString: String, method: String, headers: [String: String]?, body: String?, completion: @escaping ([UInt8]?, Int?, [String: Any]?, Error?) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            completion(nil, nil, nil, NSError(domain: "Invalid URL", code: -1, userInfo: nil))
            return
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = method
        request.httpShouldHandleCookies = false
        request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData

        if let headers = headers {
            for (key, value) in headers {
                request.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
            }
        }

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20.0
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 20.0
        var myDelegate: MySession? = nil
        if (method == "POST") {
            myDelegate = MySession()
            request.httpBody = body!.data(using: .utf8)!
            request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }

        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: myDelegate, delegateQueue: nil)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                completion(nil, nil, nil, error)
                return
            }

            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
            let responseHeaders = httpResponse.allHeaderFields as? [String: String]

            if let responseData = data {
                let byteArray = [UInt8](responseData)
                completion(byteArray, statusCode, responseHeaders, nil)
            } else {
                completion(nil, statusCode, responseHeaders, nil)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

I am desperately trying to understand why this doesn't work when everyone says it should, and Apple's documentation doesn't help. It's like the concept of redirection doesn't exist for them.

Comment: Your goal is to prevent redirection and stay on the same screen right ?

Comment: @AbiolaAkinnubi This is a special case where we just need some data from the headers and stop there. But I can't get that data if I get the result of the redirection...

Comment: Okay. can you edit your question and put a comment on where you want your code to stop execution if the header value exist?

Comment: It should stop no matter what. The endpoint called here will always return a redirect, hence why there's no logic in the function "URLSession" in the class "MySession". But if I wanted to put logic on whether the redirect should proceed it would be there.

Comment: You did not get my point. I wanted to know at what point you need this so I can give you a hint or something. But in any event.. you should put an empty return in your completion handler. e.g `return` or break once all the header data has been retrieved from the request.

Comment: I can't retrieve the data, because URLSession goes along with the redirect. This is the whole point of the question, the redirect must not happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256543/discussion-between-surnamet-and-abiola-akinnubi).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is the final solution:

```
class MySession: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    // Handles redirection
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: (URLRequest?) -> Void) {
        // Stops the redirection, and returns (internally) the response body.
        print("PASSING") // Never fires
        completionHandler(nil)
    }
}
```

Can you see it? That's right, there's an underscore at the beginning of the signature.

Comment: And the capitalization is different.. For the future, using autocomplete is a great way to make sure you're matching the signature

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering but, will make it into Community Wiki, as the author solved his/her issue, but was kind of "angry" in his/her answer.

Quick reminder on "Why a delegate method isn't called?" usual leads for debugging:

- Delegate isn't set: you declared a delegate, but never set it.
- Delegate is set on wrong instance: It's almost the same as before, but you set the delegate, except that you set it into a NEW instance, not the one you think of.
- Delegate Instance is deallocated too soon: when arrives the time that the delegate method is called, the object being the delegate is already not in memory
- Instance is deallocated too soon: The object which you are delegate isn't in memory, so it won't call the delegate (as usually delegate are weak to avoid memory retain circle)
- You don't implement the correct method. That's your case here. And since theses delegate methods are optional, you didn't get a warning saying that you didn't had implemented it.

You implemented:

```
func URLSession(session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: (URLRequest?) -> Void) {
    ...
}
```

But according to the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/1411626-urlsession), the method is:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping @Sendable (URLRequest?) -> Void
)
```

Which is slightly but significantly different. So remove it, start rewriting it and let autocomplete help you.

Just remember that

```
let value = 3
print(vAlue)
```

Shouldn't compile, because `vAlue` != `value`.

So your method wasn't the correct one.

```
func methodA() {}
func methodB() {}
```

These are two different methods, their signature are different.
Internally,